Blazor @key inside the component
I went through the docs of Blazor @key usage. But I am not sure if it works correctly in one specific case that wasn't mentioned there.
What happens if instead of this code in Page.razor:
<div>
    @foreach (var person in people)
    {
        <Details @key="person" Person="@person" />
    }
</div>

I would place the @key inside the Details component itself. So for Details.razor it would look like:
<div @key=@Person>
    @* The rest of the component UI *@
</div>

@code{
    [Parameter] public required Person Person { get; set; }
}

because that way when I loop this component in multiple pages I dont have to always specify the @key parameter in the foreach. But does the blazor take it as the same/different scope ?

I don't think there's a way to do this. As the document said, the @key should be added to the same level such as
<div @key=person1>
<div @key=person2>
...

But when you put this in a child component. You actually wrap them like:
<Details>
    <div @key=person1>
</Details>
<Details>
    <div @key=person2>
</Details>

The @key scopes are isolated by each "details" so wouldn't work as you expected. The document also mentioned

Keys are local to each container element or component. Keys aren't compared globally across the document.


I understand but there isnt specified what "same level" means. Because in the context of DOM these things ARE on the same level.

@Kebechet - but not in Blazor's virtual DOM.

I have received a final answer from Blazor team:
The key needs to be known before the component is instantiated and can't be defined from inside the component itself. https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/58339#issuecomment-2405389533
